# DNN module development with Razor and C#

Tags: c#, razor, dotnetnuke

I want to add a Razor module to my CMS which was created by DNN. In that razor module I need to show data from database. What would be the best way to do it.
Need a help

Thank you,
Nayanajith

Answer (score 0):

Add an instance of the Razor Host module to a page, and start from there. If you look at the Wiki on dnnsoftware.com, you'll find some more stuff.

For more than complicated uses, that a look at the 2sxc module free at sexycontent.codeplex.com.

If you are planning to get data from the DNN database, you'll want to learn about the DNN api.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution to my problem.

- I created a Empty ASP.NET project in visual studio.
- Then added Razor page in to that particular project (remember to
  delete configuration file).
- Then I use connection string and created normal database access class
  and added functions which I needed.
- Then published the ASP.net Web application and put it in to the DNN
  DesktopModule/RazorModule folder and created the module from the DNN
  admin.

Now it works fine :)

Comment: For additional information anyone who want to develop a Razor script just simply Create a Razor page and add it to your module directory inside DNN then create a module from host account. You do not want to create a project or solution. :)